# embbed seaborn over matplotlib with pyqt

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Hi on the below code I'd like to embbed a `sns.distplot` instead of `mpl.hist`
Yet I do not know how to modify my code as less as possible.
I'd like to put modification in `def csv2histo`, but do not know handle to modify my `pyqt` code.

The goal is to put as few code as possible I can still understand and continue developpement
This script is intended to import data from sorting machine.

Thanks in advance

```
    def csv2histo(self,df):
        df.columns = head
        print (df)
        i=1
        for C in df.columns[4:]:
            self.graph = self.fig.add_subplot(3,2,i)
            self.fig.hist(df[C].dropna(),25)
            i += 1
        self.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: The code that you have posted is way to long for StackOverflow. You should always try to remove as much code as possible to isolate the problem and make it easier for people to help you. And if your code creates an error, you should post it!!!
From briefly skimming through it, I believe this might help: Change this line `self.fig.sns.distplot(df[C].dropna(),25)` to `sns.distplot(df[C].dropna(),25, ax=self.graph)`.

Comment: Ok Thanks for your comment. I updated my code as it was first focusing on the wanted section (I firstly thought it would help to have the full code). You suggestion worked nicely thanks !

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that you shouldn't just remove code and break the functionality. The idea is to get a minimal, runable example that still reproduces the problem you face. [This guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) explains it well.